# Global messages in Hybris

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

In cart page there is a custom component to display the wishlist items.
Can I use global error message to display the messages in the custom component.
I have tried displaying the same in custom component.But the error message is not getting displayed.
Is it possible to use the global message in custom component.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use global messages in custom CMS components.

1. Include globalMessages tag in the customcomponent.jsp

   <%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/common"%>

   <common:globalMessages />
2. Add the error message in the fillmodel() method of your CustomComponentController.java

   ```
       GlobalMessages.addErrorMessage(model, "your.error.msg.key");
   ```